# Generics override confusion

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have the following class structure.

```
public abstract class X { }
public class Y extends X { }
```

And I want to do the following:

```
public abstract class Action {
  public abstract <T extends X> void execute(T t);
}

public class SomeAction extends Action {
  public void execute(Y y) { }
}
```

The compiler is giving me following error:

> The Type `SomeAction` must implement the inherited abstract method `Action.execute(T)`

I do want to override `execute()`, but I want the parameter to be a subclass of `X`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `T extends X` to be a property of the *class* extending `Action`, not the method invocation.  You should write

```
 public abstract class Action<T extends X> {
   public abstract void execute(T t);
 }
```

and then

```
 public class SomeAction extends Action<Y> {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making the class `Action` generic, instead of one of its methods.

```
public abstract class Action<T extends X>
{
   public abstract void execute(T t);
}
```

Then you can assign the generic type parameter `T` to be `Y` in `SomeAction`:

```
public class SomeAction extends Action<Y>
{
   public void execute(Y y) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public <T extends X> void execute(T t);
```

is an abstract method as it does not have any body. it should be marked as abstract.

So in your child class you need to override this or mark both method and subclass as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking the Liskov principle: the base Action's `execute` method is able to execute any kind of X. But in the subclass, you limit it to executing only Y instances. That's reducing the contract, instead of extending it.

Comment: So what? It still defines a contract through its public methods, and all the implementations must obey to the contract.

Comment: The generic method in the Action class relates to calling it with a type and having it return the same type. It doesn't relate to overriding of the method. The override, as @JBNizet has explained, has to match the signature of the method in the parent ... including the generic aspects of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the discussion. My original issue is that I want to have multiple actions, but each of them have different parameters. Is there a good way to take care of it? I can start another question if you want.